# A Stokes' like theorem for the integral of Ricci curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, curvature

Let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. In Normal coordinates around a point $p$, we have the equality:
$$
R(p) = -\frac{3}{2} \langle g , \Delta_\text{LB}g \rangle(p) \tag{1}
$$
Where $R$ is the Ricci scalar, $\langle , \rangle$ is the tensor contraction and, $\Delta_\text{LB} = d\circ \delta+\delta \circ d$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator. Now take a boundary $(\partial \mathcal{M}, \gamma)$, with $\gamma$ the first fundamental form on $\mathcal{M}$. We have for the trace $K$ of the second fundamental form:
$$
K(p) = \frac{1}{2} \langle \Gamma , \mathcal{L}_\textbf{n} \Gamma \rangle(p) \tag{2}
$$
With $\mathcal{L}_\textbf{n} = d\circ \iota_\textbf{n}+\iota_\textbf{n}\circ d$ the Lie derivative along the unit normal $n$ to the boundary, and $\Gamma$ is just $\gamma$ but with the same number of components as $g$ (so $\Gamma = g-n\otimes n$).

Now, let $\mathbb{B}_p^\epsilon$ be a closed subset of $\mathcal{M}$ with infinitesimal measure $\mu_g(\mathbb{B}_p^\epsilon)=\epsilon^d$ ($d$ is the dimension of $\mathcal{M}$), and whose boundary $\partial \mathbb{B}_p^\epsilon$ contains $p$. I am searching for a theorem that would link $(1)$ and $(2)$ in the following form:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{B}_p^\epsilon}{}^{(n)}\star \langle g , \Delta_\text{LB}g \rangle \propto \int_{\partial \mathbb{B}_p^\epsilon}{}^{(n-1)}\star\langle \Gamma , \mathcal{L}_\textbf{n} \Gamma \rangle \tag{3}
$$
For ${}^{(i)}\star$ the Hodge dual in $i$ dimensions. In fact, I have done calculations that lead to the conclusion of this proportionality, and a couple of simulations in Python that tend to show $(3)$ (but not enough to be sure it is no coincidence). So is there any known theorem that states the proportionality $(3)$?

Comment: It could be that I am misinterpreting this, but it looks very similar to the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem (or one of its generalizations to higher dimensions). You can relate the integral of the scalar curvature on a manifold with the integral of the boundary curvature, using the Euler characteristic of the manifold. In your case, the manifold in question would be the n-disk, that has Euler characteristic 1. Quick reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#Generalizations